# How can i divide a snapshot into pieces with xcode so that i can make the user interact with each of the pieces?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

My app's requirement is that it needs to take a picture and then divide it into pieces. Say for example there are 8 rows and eight columns. I might name the rows to A through H while i might name the colums to be from 1 through 8. Suppose the user after clicking the picture were to select A1, the code should be able to zoom A1 and provide him with options to do a couple of things like placing some symbols or marking a few things from the available options. How do i achive the 1)splitting 2)zooming 3)providing various symbols to the user in the form of small logos ? I am quite new to iphone programming and found out that there exists a class called UIImagePickerController to help you with that but i do not know how to achieve 1,2 and 3. Please help me.

Comment: 1. Use UIImage and CoreGraphics. Google "Crop UIImage".
2. How you'll present zoomed piece? At the same screen or it'll be pushed in the new view?
3. What kind of symbols? Small images? Use many UIImageViews and catch Drag Events for them.

Finally, show us some code so we can help you with issues. No one will write your code for you.

Comment: I do not have the code ready because i am in the planning stage. That is why looking into resources for how each of these steps could be achieved. Could you help me?

Comment: @AndreyChevozerov 2) The aim of zooming in is to let the users put the various symbols in that area. consider that the picture consists of 3x3 9 units such that the rows are named from A-C and columns form 1-3 so A1 should appear and allow the user put something like a triangular symbol. Now the triangular symbol could mean something like density or brightness.Each symbol has a meaning to itself.

Comment: @AndreyChevozerov 3) Symbols - Triangle, Circle, Square etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for dividing image into pieces you should use the following code (place it in `UIImage` category):

```
- (UIImage *)imageCroppedWithRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (self.scale > 1.0f) {
        rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * self.scale,
                          rect.origin.y * self.scale,
                          rect.size.width * self.scale,
                          rect.size.height * self.scale);
    }

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, rect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:self.scale orientation:self.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}
```

Now you'll have some images and should create appropriate amount of `UIImageViews` with those images. Then depending of how you want to let the user zoom it add `UITapGestureRecognizer`, e.q.. For zooming you could add hidden `UIImageView` and when the piece is tapped use the following code:

```
- (void)pieceTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UIImageView *piece = recognizer.view;
    self.zoomedImageView.frame = piece.frame;
    self.zoomedImageView.image = piece.image;
    self.zoomedImageView.hidden = NO;
    [UIView animationWithDuration:0.3 animation:^{
        self.zoomedImageView.frame = self.view.frame;
    }];
}
```

And now you should only place your symbols to that image. But how you want to do that? Drag & drop image from somewhere or automatically? Place symbols to the image permanently or just place over it?